# Show hidden Div running into my footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height

I have a problem when showing hidden (`display: none`) elements using `jQuery`. It's the last `div` before my `footer` and when I display the hidden `div`, it seems to run into my footer.

When I show it on certain screens it works (works fine from full view on my MacBook Pro). I'm thinking it's some kind of `div` height issue but I'm not too sure. I've tried various fixes from other height related `jQuery` issues on StackOverflow, but can't seem to find one that works for me.

I have an unordered list with 4 list elements, that when highlighted, show some additional information under them. The height of the 4 `li` elements are different because of word count, so I changed the display settings for a minute to get the heights of them and they were:

- Network 128px
- Learn 51px
- Promote 77px
- Perform 77px

And here is the code I'm using..

HTML

```
<ul>
 <li id="learn">LEARN</li>
 <li id="promote">PROMOTE</li>
 <li id="network">NETWORK</li>
 <li id="perform">PERFORM</li>
</ul>

<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="innerwrap">
          <div id="learninfo">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="large-12 columns">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae adipisci assumenda, atque magnam! Quod laboriosam quo reprehenderit deleniti omnis ipsum nulla explicabo eos hic labore, atque pariatur voluptatum earum ut minus repellendus nesciunt voluptas dolorum, natus distinctio architecto? Voluptatibus delectus odio iste voluptate harum officiis eligendi laboriosam mollitia error expedita quas perferendis corrupti natus alias, quam sapiente, magnam repellendus, vitae enim magni. Nesciunt nam odio rerum cumque quibusdam voluptates dolore est quas unde reiciendis. Dolore laborum, fugiat praesentium aperiam quisquam.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="promoteinfo">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="large-12 columns">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae adipisci assumenda, atque magnam! Quod laboriosam quo reprehenderit deleniti omnis ipsum nulla explicabo eos hic labore, atque pariatur voluptatum earum ut minus repellendus nesciunt voluptas dolorum, natus distinctio architecto? Voluptatibus delectus odio iste voluptate harum officiis eligendi laboriosam mollitia error expedita quas perferendis corrupti natus alias, quam sapiente, magnam repellendus, vitae enim magni. Nesciunt nam odio rerum cumque quibusdam voluptates dolore est quas unde reiciendis. Dolore laborum, fugiat praesentium aperiam quisquam.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="networkinfo">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="large-12 columns">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae adipisci assumenda, atque magnam! Quod laboriosam quo reprehenderit deleniti omnis ipsum nulla explicabo eos hic labore, atque pariatur voluptatum earum ut minus repellendus nesciunt voluptas dolorum, natus distinctio architecto? Voluptatibus delectus odio iste voluptate harum officiis eligendi laboriosam mollitia error expedita quas perferendis corrupti natus alias, quam sapiente, magnam repellendus, vitae enim magni. Nesciunt nam odio rerum cumque quibusdam voluptates dolore est quas unde reiciendis. Dolore laborum, fugiat praesentium aperiam quisquam.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="performinfo">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="large-12 columns">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae adipisci assumenda, atque magnam! Quod laboriosam quo reprehenderit deleniti omnis ipsum nulla explicabo eos hic labore, atque pariatur voluptatum earum ut minus repellendus nesciunt voluptas dolorum, natus distinctio architecto? Voluptatibus delectus odio iste voluptate harum officiis eligendi laboriosam mollitia error expedita quas perferendis corrupti natus alias, quam sapiente, magnam repellendus, vitae enim magni. Nesciunt nam odio rerum cumque quibusdam voluptates dolore est quas unde reiciendis. Dolore laborum, fugiat praesentium aperiam quisquam.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.innerwrap {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
#learninfo, #promoteinfo, #networkinfo, #performinfo {
    display: none;
    color: #fcb702;
}
#learn:hover, #promote:hover, #network:hover, #perform:hover {
    color: $primary-color;
}
```

jQuery

```
// Learn information display 
$("#learn").hover(function (e){

    //This funciton defines what happens on mouse-in or hover
    $("#learninfo").show();       

    }, function (e) {

    //This function defines what happens on mouse-out or when the hover is over
    $("#learninfo").hide();
});
```

(^ The jquery of course is written 4 times considering the 4 li elements) Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: #learn,#promote,#network, and #perform I used a id for each list element so that upon hover I could change the font color and single out what li element shows what hidden div

Comment: What about `learninfo`? Do you use `#networkinfo`?

Comment: yea when I highlight `li #learn` the jquery shows the hidden `div #learninfo` it's the same for all 4 `li` elements I just didn't want to paste the full jquery code since it's the same thing 4 times just replacing the `#id`. so `li #network` shows `div #networkinfo` when hovered.

Comment: Is that `CSS` or `LESS`?

Comment: It's `SASS`but I think the problem is merely in jquery I need something to add height to the outer `div` when I show the `display:none;` one.

Comment: @afaolek Have you included jQuery?

Comment: How about the `HTML` code?

Comment: Yes, the show/hide is working just fine it's just I need it to make the div height longer when displaying the hidden content because the text will run into my footer.

Comment: @afaolek Edited it in the question. Of course that's not the text I used and my text in my real code is wrapped in a <p> tag but it's almost the same amount of words. I just want a way to make it so that when I show the hidden div at hover for it to adjust the height as need be (if it's possible).

Comment: Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ULq2/1/). It does not answer the height problem, though. That is a `CSS` stuff. Maybe the classes, `large-12` and `columns`, are affecting the layout.

Comment: I'm not new to html/css I'm positive that's not effecting it.  It's simply that I don't know how to add height using jquery when I show a hidden `div`.